# I need to periodically power up the monitor

Tags: windows-7, display, troubleshooting, energy-saving

At work, I have a really bad monitor (generic trademark with unknown model/manufacturer) which sometimes goes randomly off.
It is connected with a VGA cable (not HDMI).

I believe that goes to some energy saving mode. It does not powers on no matter what I do.

I plugged it to 2 different PCs, and it behaves the same, so I think is a hardware problem of the monitor, and not a software one.

If I push the shutdown button of the PC (windows 7 64), it awakes the monitor to ask if I really want to shutdown/show the list of running programs.
That's the only way in which it powers on (unless I reboot the PC).

I'm looking for some command line, script or program which sends the command to awake to the monitor, periodically (maybe once a minute, or each 10 seconds).

Do you know any software solution?

Comment: Have you tried just adjusting the power settings in Windows?

Comment: @Digital. Yes, I checked the power settings. They are set to never shutdown the monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nir Sofer has a tool for that...

```
nircmd.exe monitor off
nircmd.exe monitor on
```

tool ref: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html
PS: download is in the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you. I had it set to run every minute with the windows 7 task scheduler. I will mark your answer as correct as soon as I'm allowed.